# Google PerfKit tool: Where are the results of the benchmark run stored

Tags: cloud

I am trying to use the new google perfkit tool. I followed the procedure in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker and trying to run the below command:

> ..\GoogleCloud\Perfkit\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.10.0\perfkitbenchmarker\pkb.py --project=24Feb2015 --benchmarks=ping --machine_type=f1-micro > my.log

I see that my.log is empty. I tried a lot to run individual benchmark python files as well, but unable to see any results.

Can you please help on the below:
1. Does perfkit itself create VMs on the google cloud and run the benchmark tests specified in --benchmark option above? When I ran the above command, I couldn't see any VM created on google cloud.

2. Why are my benchmark results empty?

Also was curious about the below:

3. At present only aws, google, azure cloud providers are supported. What does it take to support other cloud providers?
4. Right now predefined benchmarks are run, is there a way to include custom benchmark tests also?

(I authenticated my google cloud account, deployed a sample aerospike app).

Thanks a lot!
Sushma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it fully provisions the system including creating VM's
2. Are you running this from a Windows machine?  If so are you running inside CYGWIN? See my output from your command below.
3. We also support static machine (ie anything with an IP).  Adding a new provider is not that difficult.  We have plans for OpenStack.  See the issues on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker
4. Yes but it takes work to do the automation.  Check out the benchmarks directory to see how it is done for various benchmarks today.

When I run on my LINUX machine I see the following:

```
./pkb.py --project=google.com:voellm --benchmarks=ping --machine_type=f1-micro > my.log

2015-03-16 11:19:23,848 INFO     Verbose logging to: /tmp/perfkitbenchmarker/run_5653144d/pkb.log
2015-03-16 11:19:24,087 INFO     Preparing benchmark ping
2015-03-16 11:19:24,088 INFO     Running: gcloud compute disks create perfkit-5653144d-1 --size 10 --type pd-standard --project google.com:voellm --format json --quiet --zone us-central1-a --image ubuntu-14-04
2015-03-16 11:19:24,088 INFO     Running: gcloud compute disks create perfkit-5653144d-0 --size 10 --type pd-standard --project google.com:voellm --format json --quiet --zone us-central1-a --image ubuntu-14-04
2015-03-16 11:19:35,170 INFO     Running: gcloud compute disks describe perfkit-5653144d-1 --project google.com:voellm --format json --quiet --zone us-central1-a
...
```